# ViewPager swiping with a VideoView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I've a VideoView in one of the fragment displayed by my ViewPager. Swiping works well on every Fragment but the one with the video one.

It seems to be that the VideoView is catching the swiping event.

Any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: If I were you I would disable viewpager swiping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this works but theoretically you just need to stop VideoView from consuming your onTouch event, try making a custom VideoView class, and override onTouch method, by returning always false.

Comment: returning `true` on `boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` did the job, thanks !